# CPP Accessing a map with a non-existing key

Tags: c++

In this function, a vector of integers and an integer is given as "nums" and "target"

I tried created a hash table with a key as target-nums[i] and a value as # of that keys

for example, `if nums = [3, 3, 4, 5], target = 7`

```
 key -> value

   |  4  ->   2

   |  3  ->   1

   |  2  ->   1
```

and code for function is,

```
vector<int> twoSum(vector<int>& nums, int target) {
    int first=0;
    int second=0;
    map<int, int> HT;
    vector<int> sol;

    for(vector<int>::iterator i=nums.begin(); i<nums.end();i++){
        if(HT[target-*i]==NULL)
            HT.insert(pair<int, int>(target - *i, 1));
        else
            HT[target-*i]++;

    }
}
```

However, it gives an error message of

```
==31==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x602000000060 at pc 0x0000004193d5 bp 0x7ffe5e3cd950 sp 0x7ffe5e3cd948
READ of size 4 at 0x602000000060 thread T0
    #2 0x7f66b38802e0 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x202e0)"
```

Under the for loop, the if condition `HT[target-*i]==NULL` seems like it's never true.

I thought in CPP, if I access a non-existing key, it immediately initializes with a value NULL.

If so, that condition must be true whenever it sees a new key.

Which part am I wrong?

Comment: Are you saying the else part is generating the message?

if I test it with a vector like [1,2,3] where no value overlaps, 
thus HT[target-*i] is always a new key,
it still generates the same error message

Comment: @parktomatomi But OP is inserting into `HT` which is a map though. The vector `sol` is never touched.

Comment: @SacrificerXY yup, totally misread it. Will delete my comment to avoid confusion.

Comment: Suggestion: You can simplify the for loop by using a [ranged-based for loop](https://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-ranged-for-loop.html)

Comment: I tested your code and it doesn't crash/error https://godbolt.org/z/mkdCpn

Comment: @SacrificerXY exit code is 255 :)

Comment: Ah, but it doesn't crash if you add `return {};` to return a valid vector. I wonder that's the OP's issue.

Comment: Just a suggestion: Instead of `if(HT[target-*i]==NULL)`, a much better alternative is to use `map.count(target-*i)` function which returns 1 if the key is present in the map and returns 0 if not.

Comment: I guess the `if-else` is unnecessary altogether. OP can just do `HT[target-*i]++;` for all cases since it will default to zero when the key doesn't exists.

Comment: Is there any reason [std::unordered_map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) wouldn't work for you out-of-the-box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `if(HT[target-*i]==NULL)`, the `[]` operator of `std::map` automatically inserts the requested key if it is not found.  Your map holds int values, not pointers, so comparing them to NULL is wrong.

The correct way to detect if a given key is present in the map is to use the `map::find()` method and the iterator that it returns, eg

```cpp
map<int, int> HT;
vector<int> sol;

for(vector<int>::iterator i = nums.begin(); i != nums.end(); ++i){
    map<int, int>::iterator found = HT.find(target - *i);
    if (found == HT.end())
        HT.insert(make_pair(target - *i, 1));
    else
        found->second++;
}

// populate and return sol as needed...
```

However, there is no need to manually search and insert keys. It would be easier to just let the map auto-insert new keys for you. The default value of an auto-inserted value will be 0, which you would then increment to 1 when you call the `++` operator on a newly inserted value, eg:

```cpp
map<int, int> HT;
vector<int> sol;

for(vector<int>::iterator i = nums.begin(); i != nums.end(); ++i){
    HT[target - *i]++;
}

// populate and return sol as needed...
```

If you are using C++11 or later, use a range-based for loop to simply the loop:

```cpp
map<int, int> HT;
vector<int> sol;

for(int i : nums){
    HT[target - i]++;
}

// populate and return sol as needed...
```

Comment: Thank you! this was what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

`if(HT[target-*i]==NULL)`

This is a nonsense. This will always add a new key. Use count instead
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/count/

`if(HT.count(target-*i) == 0)`

or,

`if(HT.find(target-*i) == HT.end())`

Answer (score 0):

A function which fails to return a value when it should(i.e the `twoSum` function) will result in **undefined behavior**. So anything can happen ([Can undefined behavior erase the hard drive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18506029/can-undefined-behavior-erase-the-hard-drive)).

The compiler will normally give a warning about this but you can promote it into an error by using the `-Werror=return-type` compiler flag.

See this post for more info: [Why does this C++ snippet compile (non-void function does not return a value)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20614282/why-does-this-c-snippet-compile-non-void-function-does-not-return-a-value)