Conesequences of Headers Mis-Matching A Library?
I've come to realize that there are times whilst developing a C++ library where including implementation code in the .h files associated with the library becomes unavoidable. An example of such a time is when developing a template of a method, class, etc.
I already understand that a template of something transforms what that something represents from a concrete implementation of itself to instructions for the compiler to follow when creating concrete implementations behind usages of the template'd something. In the context of library development, this tells me that moving implementation code of a template method, class, etc. out from the file that declares the template isn't possible or else those who link the library will not have the instructions necessary to compile concrete implementations behind uses of the template (among other reasons one cannot have implementation code for a template in a different file than the declaration of the template).
With the above example specifically in mind, what are the consequences to the one linking a library in the case that one or more .h files that come with the library do not exactly match the contents of the library itself?
I have already accepted that there is simply no way I can give templates of things to those who link the library without including the full implementation code in the .h files that declare these templates since it just doesn't make sense otherwise. I should also add that in the greater context of what I am trying to achieve I cannot concrete implement all variations of the templates in this example in question because I want the linker of the library to be able to concrete implement their own variations on these templates. That said, I just want to know what would happen if someone linking the library attempted to tamper with the .h files. Would the compile fail? Would linking fail? Would the build succeed and just produce a ton of runtime errors? I'd test myself in an MRE but I'm not confident enough with library development to know if any results from that MRE are themselves the result of my own ineptitude.
Thanks for reading!

There is no general answer to this. All outcomes are possible. You seem to be assuming that some kind of error would occur, but even that is not guaranteed.

what are the consequences to the one linking a library in the case that one or more .h files that come with the library do not exactly match the contents of the library itself? Possible undefined behavior if the difference in the header is in the code and not just comments.

Template header files are always compiled in the context of the translation unit compiling that header file (the code will not be part of a static or dynamic library) so those will not be the problem. If the declaration (header) does not match the definition (implementation) you have an issue. Note that the standard library mostly takes care of avoiding this, lookup ABI compatibility.

Also note that if you link an executable with multiple versions of the same static library which can happen through transitive dependencies of other libraries.  Your problem also occurs, and it may break ODR (one definition rule) and you end up not knowing which version of the implementation is actually linked. So TLDR: be very very careful with version managment ;)

Some handy reading. The behaviour of Undefined Behaviour is, you guessed it, undefined.

A mismatch between definitions (definitions of inlined functions [which includes templated functions], definitions of types, etc) in a header file and definitions (of the same things) in a library breaks the one-definition rule, so causes undefined behaviour according to the standard.  Consequences can include not building correctly, not running correctly if it does build correctly. Even worse, another developer who builds your program and/or library (say, using a different toolchain) may experience something different to you (e.g. it builds/runs correctly for you, but not them).

I don't see how templates matter. If FOO.DLL defines int foo(int); and someone changes foo.h to float foo(float);, they already have Undefined Behavior. The advice is simple: don't do that.


what are the consequences to the one linking a library in the case that one or more .h files that come with the library do not exactly match the contents of the library itself?

It might simply crash and burn in ways that are impossible to foresee. Yes, that includes you deleting all the user's files.
It might work, if the only difference in ABI is between symbols you are not using.
It might not even produce code that can be linked, and so you might not even be able to produce a binary.
So, it depends.

I see, very troubling but also kind of expected. I guess I'll just have to trust that whoever's using the library won't alter any of the .h files since it would cause nothing but trouble if they had good intentions. Thank you for the answer, though! I'll accept it as an answer as soon as StackOverflow lets me, I've got a timer upon letting that happen fsr.

Marcus I always have a little problem with the doomsday scenarios like deleting files/formatting hard drives etc. etc. These sounde spectacular, but the "unseen" errors like subtle memory corruptions are much more likely and much harder to detect.
I think it is better to ask "How to avoid this kind of versioning issues" than to exactly describe what could go wrong, it is much safer to assume that when you have a version mismatch things will go wrong (unless great care has been taken to make compatible versions, and that should be documented)

I use more absurd examples, like the program hacking into the Pentagon and ordering a nuclear strike on your backyard. THAT is a doomsday scenario.

@PepijnKramer: Deleting files is a real danger, though: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18506556/15416.
